# Swift3: How to write a String with comma?

Tags: swift3

Why is the "2,78" String not possible?

```
  func action1()
    {
    time1 += 2,78
    lbltime.text = String(time1)
    }
```

Comment: Please improve your question. "Why is the "2,78" String not possible?" is clear only for you...

Comment: There is a Error: Binary '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Double'

Comment: @FLORIAN, Can you please edit your question & add full stacktrace of the error you're getting?

Comment: Declare `time1` as a Double.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a localized representation of a number, use a `NumberFormatter`:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

let x = Float.pi
if let string = formatter.string(for: x) {
    print("string:", string)
}
```

On device with, for example, with German locale with `,` as decimal separator, that will report:

> string: 3,14

But for locales that use a `.` for the decimal separator, it will report:

> string: 3.14